# Connect google cloud function 2nd gen to mysql of another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have the following command to deploy a google cloud function.

I use the same command to deploy a google cloud function of gen1 ( except the flag `--gen2` ) and everything works fine. In the project that has the database, i have set the role of `Cloud Sql Client` with the service account that is set in the command.

But when i deploy a google cloud function of gen2, i can't connect to the database of the other project. Given that `gen2` cloud functions use `Cloud Run` i have also checked the `service-account` that `Cloud Run` uses, and it matches the `service account` that has the `Cloud Sql Client` in the project that has the database.

I get this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

```
      gcloud functions deploy $CLOUD_FUNCTION_NAME-staging-gen2
      --gen2
      --source=./src
      --runtime=$CLOUD_FUNCTION_PHP_VERSION
      --trigger-http
      --entry-point=$CLOUD_FUNCTION_ENTRY_POINT
      --allow-unauthenticated
      --region=$GCP_ZONE
      --project=$PROJECT_ID
      --env-vars-file .env.yml
      --min-instances=$MINIMUM_NUMBER_OF_INSTANCES
      --service-account=*******@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
      ${VPC_CONNECTOR:+--vpc-connector projects/$PROJECT_ID/locations/$GCP_ZONE/connectors/$VPC_CONNECTOR}
```

I have also tried to not set the `--service-account` when i deploy and let it use the default. Then i added the default service account to the project which has the database, in the IAM section with the role of `Cloud Sql Client` but it still does not work.

I use `unix_socket` to connect to the database, because the database is hosted in another project.

```
"mysql:dbname=${dbname};port=${port};unix_socket=/cloudsql/${instanceConnectionName}"
```

Where `instanceConnectionName` is project_name:europe-west4:database_name

Comment: How do you reach the database? do you use private IP and network peering between projects?

Comment: I have updated my question. It now includes the way i try to connect to the database.

Comment: If you don't specify the Cloud SQL connection in the cloud function deployment, the linux socket won't be open. Tha'ts why, I asked on HOW do you connect the database.

Comment: I do specify it. It is available as an environment variable, but it is not in the command that i wrote above. As i mentioned also in my question, if i do exact same thing for Gen1 Cloud  function, everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions, you have to add the connection to the cloud run service that is automatically deployed with the gen 2 cloud function. This is the case for other database types as well. Scroll to "If you're using Cloud Functions (2nd gen) and not Cloud Functions (1st gen)"